# Jupyter misdisplying Python lists with Arabic and alphanumeric elements

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter, arabic, spyder

I am running into a display problem in Jupyter (both Classic and JupyterLab) for lists that include Arabic string elements and Latin Alphanumeric string elements. For example, if you run:

```
en = '7X'
print (en)
ar = 'عربي'
print (ar)
print ([en, ar])
print ([ar, en])
```

Here is what you get:

[image]

Obviously, where Arabic is the first element, Jupyter follows an RTL alignment displaying the `ar` element first on the right, but I don't know why the `'X'` jumps from the alphanumeric element or how to fix that.

By the way, this is how Spyder prints out the same code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the print out to switch it to the correct position.

```
>>> print([ar,en])
['عربي', '7X']
#Click Here^
```

I believe this is an error that only applies to Arabic. I tried it with Chinese without problem. I'll try to do more research on it and update this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Clicking on the console is not a solution though (and that only works in certain IDEs). The problem is a systematic one, and it has now been taken up by the developers.