# How do I insert <br> tag in Arabic Left to Right (LTR) text

Tags: arabic, line-breaks, right-to-left

I have this Arabic sample text:

```
<span class="message4" id="message4" data-gwd-tl-locked="" data-gwd-tl-hidden="">نص العنوان الرئيسي هنا <br> على سطرين</span>
```

I managed to copy paste a line break in there. Actually I pasted it in between two other words but it moved towards the right.

I got no clue what is going on, sorry. Is it even possible to get a line break into **ARABIC** text? And why does it, like a wild chicken, move position when I paste it into a location.

Should I just make my containers reflow text and skip line break for ARABIC?

Thanks in Advance

Thomas

Comment: I don't understand your question. The example you have works for me.

Comment: Yes but, hmm. I pasted the <br> tag some words to the left. When it was pasted it moved some words to the right automatically? Don't know Arabic but is that expected behaviour.

Comment: This looks fine; what editor are you using and exactly how are you entering it? I suspect your editor is having trouble with bidirectional text rules, which are very tricky. Which two words do you want the break between?

Comment: But I think you've got your text backwards. It reads "On two lines ...line break... Headline text here." I assume you mean the other way around?

Comment: Hello @RobNapier . Thanks for the help! I'm using VS Code. Interesting so it might be the software itself? Hmm wonder how I got it that way it reshuffled when I pasted break tag. Will check. I see now that VS code reverses the words when I paste them in. Investigating on their support site!

Comment: The trouble is how bidirectional (bidi) rules work. The characters `<`, `>`, and ` ` are direction-neutral, so the editor probably wants to treat them as RTL (since the character immediately before is RTL). In some cases I find that need to open up the data in a hex editor to be absolutely certain of the character order. This is particularly tough if you don't read at least a little Arabic (I barely read Arabic, but enough for this problem).

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier , due to time constraints and that I'm getting away with sample text I will skip line breaks for now and use reflow! Still need to find a workaround though for why the text inverts itself in VSCode when I paste from Google translate, some Arabic. Will research!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is behaving as expected in bidirectional texts. You just need to acclimate your own reading habits to how Arabic is read: whether you create the Arabic string by typing or insertion, the start of the Arabic string lies at its "other end" compared to English. To see how this flows just use the right arrow to skip over the characters from the beginning of your mixed text. In a mono-directional Right-to-Left English (En) text of strings separated by spaces you will have:

```
Start(En)End Start(En)End Start(En)End Start(En)End...
```

Whereas in a bi-directional LTR/RTL text of English and Arabic (Ar) strings you will have:

```
Start(En)End End(Ar)Start Start(En)End End(Ar)Start...
```

That said, typing the whole multi-lingual string is easier than inserting chunks of them here and there. As you type, you are synchronously aware of the language/display flow and thus less surprised at the "chicken jumps!"

Furthermore, VSCode and most such editors are not designed with RTL languages in mind. To best handle Arabic in bi-directional coding use a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: When I put this in Jupyter, I see the same behavior I see in VSCode. To see the symptom I believe is being discussed, type "نص العنوان الرئيسي هنا على سطرين" and then insert `<br>` between هنا and على. (Honestly, I'm not even sure this qualifies as a bug. I'm not 100% certain what it *should* do.)

Comment: This behavior is normal and expected for RTL and LTR interaction. Let's remember that after an LTR text ends, the following RTL text always begins at its own right end. But I would still recommend Jupyter over other editors for Arabic because of its more versatile output and markdown abilities. I have tried most of the others and they are quite buggy with Arabic -- even Jupyter is not completely bug-free with Arabic. [I reported this bug to its developers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704303/jupyter-misdisplying-python-lists-with-arabic-and-alphanumeric-elements/48704672#48704672).

Comment: I will update my answer above to indicate the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out in VSCode, and I see what you're seeing, but it seems to mostly be bugs in VSCode. For example, VSCode can get very confused when you select sections of Arabic text and reformat the text as you select. (I can almost picture the mistakes in the code that probably lead to this, I assume by laying out the highlighted text separately from the non-highlighted text rather than laying it all out and then highlighting part of it.)

What I recommend, if you can get away with it, is to put LTR and RTL text on separate lines:

```
<span class="message4" id="message4" data-gwd-tl-locked="" data-gwd-tl-hidden="">
نص العنوان الرئيسي هنا 
<br/>
على سطرين
</span>
```

This formatting tends to be easier for bidi (bidirectional text) algorithms to deal with, and makes it more clear that this is "نص العنوان الرئيسي هنا" and then a break, and then "على سطرين". When you put these on a single line, it is very non-obvious, at least to me, what order the phrases are supposed to be. Is this Latin text with Arabic in the middle, or Arabic text with Latin in the middle? Adding newlines makes it much clearer IMO.